# Python making gtk.Layout with Scrollbars

Tags: python, dynamic, gtk, scrollbar

How could I have a scrollbar inside a gtk.Layout.

For example, in my code I have:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class ScrolledWindowExample:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Dialog()
        self.window.connect("destroy", self.destroy)
        self.window.set_size_request(300, 300)

        self.scrolled_window = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.scrolled_window.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)

        self.window.vbox.pack_start(self.scrolled_window, True, True, 0)

        self.layout = gtk.Layout()
        self.scrolled_window.add(self.layout)

        self.current_pos = 0
        self.add_buttom()
        self.window.show_all()

    def add_buttom(self, widget = None):
            title = str(self.current_pos)
            button = gtk.ToggleButton(title)
            button.connect_object("clicked", self.add_buttom, None)
            self.layout.put(button, self.current_pos, self.current_pos)
            button.show()
            self.current_pos += 20

    def destroy(self, widget):
        gtk.main_quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ScrolledWindowExample()
    gtk.main()
```

What I really want is to find some way to make the scroll dynamic. See the example that I put above, when you click any button, another button will be added.  But the scrollbar doesn't work.

What can I do to get  the scroll bars working?

Answer (score 0):

Does it works if you either use `gtk.Window()` instead of `gtk.Dialog()`; or execute `self.window.run()` after `self.window.show_all()`?

The difference between Dialog and common Window is that Dialog has its own loop which processes events. As you do not run its `run()` command, this loop never gets the chance to catch the events, so `ScrolledWindow` does not receives them, and does not change its size.